# If sampling from parametric copula fitted to real data, must the marginals also be simulated?

Tags: dataset, independence, copula, marginal-distribution, nonparametric

A real dataset consists of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose densities are the marginal distributions to be used. These marginals are transformed into uniform variables. As for the copula, either

1. the **empirical copula** could be used, which is based on the real data's bivariate distribution, or
2. a **parametric copula**, like the Gaussian, t-, or Frank/Gumbel/etc can be used, which are artificial data.

If the empirical copula is chosen, then the uniform transforms of the real data are used for marginal distributions.

If instead a parametric copula is chosen, i.e. I simulate the dependence structure, do the uniform transforms have to also be based an artificially-generated data, or do I still use the real data's transformed marginals?

In other words, does a parametric (simulated) copula preserve the dependence structure with the real marginals, relinquishing the need to use corresponding simulated marginals?

Comment: If you have simulated from a copula you just transform the uniform margins to whatever.

Comment: ok so the marginals can be based on the real data or they can be simulated by some time series model, no difference?

Comment: I don't understand what time series models have to do with copulas, nor exactly what you intend by "based on real data" (they can be, in several ways, but keep in mind copula theory usually assumes continuous margins).